# Limiting a combo box value by another column value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm a novice access user. I have created a form which brings through multiple values from a table, I have a column which I have as combo boxes.
What I want to do is limit these combo boxes by the value in the same ro of a different column.
Example: combo box column contains different component names on a product(red bottle, Blue bottle or red cap, blue cap) I want to limit the combo box so when you are looking at different components you are only looking at like for like , caps is a list of caps, bottles is list of bottles. Another column in the table has this value.

Comment: How did you set up your combo box? Is it getting its list of options from a table, or did you manually provide the list of options?

Comment: Also: is your form's Default View property set to `single` or `continuous`?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for responding. The form is a continuous form and the data is pulled through from a query created from a table.

Comment: I set up the combo box by creating a tabulated form and then right clicking the column that I wanted and change to combo box

Answer (score 0):

I've created [this mock-up](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiTDhxbE9iU1dQWms/view?usp=sharing), which filters the combo box options based on data from the row it resides on.

The options for the combo box come from a table I've created. This table has a column called **ComponentName**, which is what users of the form will see as the options in combo box, but there is also another column called **ComponentType**, which is what will be used later to match against the row in which the combo box will be placed.

[image]

Here's the form (set to continuous) with some component types to match on and our combo box:

[image]

When picking from the combo box, it will match the **Component Type Needed** data for the row to the table underlying the combo box options and show only those options in the combo box with the matching **Component Type**:

[image]

To achieve this, the `Row Source` property of the combo box has been set up so that it is limited in a `WHERE` clause to whatever data is in the **ComponentTypeNeeded** field for the same row on the form:

`SELECT [tblComponents].[ComponentID], [tblComponents].[ComponentType], [tblComponents].[ComponentName] FROM tblComponents WHERE [tblComponents].[ComponentType] = [ComponentTypeNeeded] ORDER BY [ComponentName];`

I've then set the `Column Widths` property of the combo box so that only the **ComponentName** column shows in the combo box (the other 2 are hidden by being set to a width of 0cm):

[image]

Hope this gives you some pointers for your project :)

Comment: Thanks Matt, will give it a go and let you know if it works for me. Looks exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for your help with this. One thing that I have noticed is that when you are on the Form in the combo boxes it only shows either Caps or Bottles but not both so on a cap line you see all line with any caps selected and on a bottle line only bottles. Is this the same when you view it or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I thought this is the behaviour you were after? "I want to limit the combo box so when you are looking at different components you are only looking at **like for like** [...] caps is a list of caps, bottles is list of bottles"

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for replying. When I'm using the combo box I want the view to be limited, however when the items are chosen I want then to stay visible. So as an example: I choose a blue bottle from the bottle combo, then move onto the cap I would still want to see which bottle has been chosen in the combo box. I want to limit the choice in the combo box, which it does but once chosen stay visible.